# Removing value from array if it is contained by another array

Tags: arrays, ruby, contain

I have two arrays

```
main_array = [[0,[1,4,5]], [1,[4,6,8]], [2,[5,6,7,8]], [3,[9,8]], [4,[7,2]]]
other_array = [[1,4,5],[9,8]]
```

What I want to do is to delete those elements in `main_array` if it can be found in `other_array`. (Meaning I will be left with `[[1,[4,6,8]], [2,[5,6,7,8]],[4,[7,2]]]` ) So I did the following:

```
other_array.each { |x|
for i in 0..main_array.length-1
  main_array.delete(x)
}
```

It didn't work. Any clues on how I should approach this?

Answer (score 2):

```
main_array.reject { |_,a| other_array.include?(a) }
  #=> [[1,[4,6,8]], [2,[5,6,7,8]], [4,[7,2]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Enumerable#reject](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html) (this is a module that is included in almost all collections in Ruby, such as Arrays, Hashes, Sets and etc.), it returns new array with removed elements, based on some condition:

```
main_array.reject { |item| other_array.include? item[1] }
```

Here `item` is every item in `main_array`. You can also "unwrap" your `item` if you want to control its elements individually:

```
main_array.reject { |(key, val)| other_array.include? val }
```

I'd recommend you to go and check the link above, there are also lots of interesting things over there.